# My reactjs component is not loading changes

Tags: reactjs, loading

I'm changing the content of my component like adding `<h3></h3>` tag, it compiles properly but when I reload the page it still remains the same.

The component I want to load:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Box } from '@mui/material';

export default class PageNotFound extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <Box>
                    <img src="static/svg/error404.svg" alt="404 error image" />
                    <h3>This page could not be found :(</h3>
                    <h3>This should load the error hopefully ;-;</h3>
                </Box>
            </Grid >
        )
    }
}
```

The image output:
[image: Output image]

Comment: Try removing browser cache. Or maybe try from a different browser/incognito mode.

Comment: The second `h3` should be printed. @SreeramVenkitesh is right. may be you need to clear your cache.

Comment: I used incognito with Chrome, FireFox and Safari. It is not working at all. @SreeramVenkitesh

Comment: Did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Yes, i did restart and also reinstalled packages.

Comment: I don't know what was the problem but I cloned my repository again, freshly installed all npm packages and copied all my modified code to new cloned repository.

Maybe the problem was reinstalling npm packages.

Comment: After few more reloads it again has the same problem it loads the first compiled file. After the changes.